# RSS feed AppStore Apple получить историю обновлений приложения

Tags: python, rss, appstore

На просторах интернета нашел только как получить фид рсс с отзывами (https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=389801252/xml), а вот как получить фид с историей обновления приложения так и не нашел может у кого получалось

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вот например приложение (https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/jungle-heat/id652136891)  мне надо получить вот эти данные [https://a.radikal.ru/a35/2109/ea/113195ef9522.png]